# PTIJ: wiping amalek’s memory?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The pasuk says (Devarim 25:18):
תמחה את זכר עמלק- wipe the memory of Amalek.
Does this mean to wipe all of their memories, or only enough to make them ‘non- Amaleki’?
Also, how do we wipe their memories-hypnosis seems pretty close to the prohibition of magic, so are there alternatives?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Wouldn’t a good klap on the head do the trick?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You only need to wipe their local memory storage. Memory in the Cloud need not be wiped, as the verse ends

> מתחת השמים

The best approach is really just to overwrite all of the memory with binary zeros, as the Spies themselves recommended (Bamidbar 13:29-30):

> אפס כי עז העם היושב בארץ... עמלק יושב בארץ
>
> Zero out the nation that lives in the Land ... Amalek lives in the Land

Comment: One of the best answers this season! +1

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Thanks! And I posted it right before tanking my daily rep cap, so it was לשמה!

Comment: Wouldn’t taking out their memory cards be simpler?

Comment: @Loani You think they’d let you anywhere near the port those cards are in? Much easier to do it remotely. All you’d have to do is hack their servers.

Comment: Good point, I hadn’t thought of that.

Comment: @Loani Are you talking about memory cards as in RAM? I thought you wanted to wipe the persistent data. Removing it will just make it inaccessible, but it won't wipe it.

Comment: Well when you take out their memory cards, you can do whatever you want with them, including destroying it

Comment: Whatever you do, don't forget the RAM. Shaul Hamelech made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I've always interpreted that pasuk to mean the wiping out of the memories of Jews(and Noahites) of any memory of Amalek.

As is usual in a lot of cases, I learned this by watching lots of Star Trek.

Starting with the original series' first season's "Dagger of the Mind" - not so coincidentally written by a 1930's Germany-fleeing Shimon Wincelberg writing under the pen name S. Bar-David - there is memory erasing "neural neutralizer" as a central plot point.  Evidently, when they started using it for other things besides wiping out the memory of Amalek, that's when the trouble started. But all turned out well for the mitzvah-observing characters in the end.

Later on, in the Next Generation/DeepSpace Nine's times, Dr Bashir used a memory eraser in the episode "Sons of Mogh" to wipe out the memory of Amalek(and a bunch of other stuff) from Worf's brother's mind for a successful conclusion to the episode.

Btw, it's obvious that Worf was raised in a Jewish household - in the Next Generation episode "Family", his adoptive parents were obviously Jewish, even being played by Theodore Bikel and Georgia Brown(!!).

Even out in the Delta Quadrant, in the episode "Unforgettable", Voyager runs into a race of people that emit an automatic Amalek(and everything else)-forgetting pheromone.  Perhaps one of the lost tribes made it out there by then and it became a genetic adaptation after so much Torah study?

So, in conclusion, at least according to Gene Roddenberry and his successors, even 500 years from now, the memory of Amalek will still be busy being wiped out.

Comment: If you read to the end of the posuk, it clarifies how we are to erase that memory. The Etnachtah under the word השמים serves like a semicolon. The 2nd phrase is, “לא תשכח”, you will forget (the word) לא in the paragraph where it speaks about Amalek. That was the phrase, “ולא ירא אלקים”. So by forgetting the לא, the Torah will say that Amalek feared G-d. In that case, they wouldn’t have attacked the Jewish people. It is using the principle of “Kri v’Kativ”, it’s written one way but read another.

Comment: @YaacovDeane - Okay.  I was just going by the Jewish English (Sefaria, Chabad) translations.  Didn't see or read any of your info there. Thanks!

Comment: I understand. That’s the disadvantage of not being able to read and comprehend in the original language. One is dependent upon what level of reading comprehension your translator has in both the original and in the language they are translating into. Good reading comprehension of Hebrew is literally the keys to G-d’s Kingdom. It is truly what makes you free of Mitzrayim.